# On json Parsing assign special carecter to variables in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When I parse my Json file on execution of this line

```
model.userProfileObj.userFirstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[responseDict valueForKey:@"Profile"] valueForKey:@"first_name"]];
```

Profile is my dictionary and first_name its inner variable. like:

```
[
    {
        "Profile": {
            "id": "13",
            "user_id": "13",
            "first_name": "Myname",
            "profile_image": "13-IMG_169.png",
        }
    }
]
```

Assign the following string to model.userProfileObj.userFirstName but I need MyName only not ( and " in variable.

```
(
    "Myname"
)
```

Comment: It looks like it's returning an object not a string, try checking the type of object returned by `[[responseDict valueForKey:@"Profile"] valueForKey:@"first_name"]`

Comment: is this your full json result or just part ?

Comment: hey bro i did a lot of work on your problem...just check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result in `responseDict` is in array format and you are using it as dictionary thats why you are getting result like this

```
(
    "Myname"
)
```

so just do one thing in your code.. `[responseDict objectAtIndex:0]`

**Your code**

```
model.userProfileObj.userFirstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[responseDict objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Profile"] valueForKey:@"first_name"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *returnString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataReceivedG encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    SBJSON *jsonParser=[[SBJSON alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *_dict=(NSDictionary *)[jsonParser objectWithString:returnString error:nil];
    NSLog(@"----%@",_dict);
    NSArray *_arrData=(NSArray *)[_dict ob
    //NSDictionary *_dictResponse=(NSDictionary *)[_objectForKey:@"profile"];
    NSLog(@"===%@",_arrData);
    for (int j=0; j<[_arrData count]; j++) 
    {
        [arrayListG addObject:[[_arrData objectAtIndex:j]valueForKey:@"first_name"]];
    }
}
```

check this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the a String with JSON contents,
you could use a regex like

```
 NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"Myname:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" options:0 error:NULL];
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:apiResponse options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [apiResponse length])];

    NSString *encodedPoints = [jsonAsString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
```